# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

when i'm dumping the data to pickle file I am getting this error ."TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"

```
with open('vocabulary-embedding.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((embedding, idx2word, word2idx),f,-1)
```

Input -->

embedding : [[0.06625115  0.01928704 -0.02624818  0.00121181  0.05762575 -0.03544753]...] .

idx2word : [on,the,for....]

word2idx :[100,12,13,15...]

Why I am getting this error ? How do i solve this?

Comment: It means that write() is expecting the data in string format, but the data being passed is in the form of bytes data.   try to replace **wb** with **w** and see how it goes.

Comment: could you give more of your code, unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: what part of code , do you want ?

Comment: @hkhr i tried replacing wb with w , it still doesnt work

Comment: Reduce the problem: does it occur if you remove for example `embedding`? `idx2word`? Remove things so you get a minimal failing example. Then what is the value and type of the remaining thing?

Comment: yeah still I'm getting the same error

Comment: is there  any other way than pickle?

Comment: Do you do other output to `f`? Do you really use "wb"? I get your error when I use "w" instead.

Comment: i'm getting the same error with ,w and wb @ArndtJonasson

Comment: Make a complete (preferably small) program which exhibits the error, and show it and the data.

Comment: The best thing to debug in this case could be , just check the type of all the data variables being passed, I mean just do print(type(embedding),type(idx2word), type(word2idx)), and print(type(f)) which will help to identify the problem.

Comment: yeah , i did it, embedding is numpy array and rest is dict